# RFID Card Have Two Different Codes Decimal and Hexadecimal

Tags: nfc

So, here's the deal: I've scanned this NFC tag with two different devices, and they're giving me different results:

**Reading 1:** 000005E4FA9D **Reader**: Promag MF700/MF7

**Reading 2:** 3108611405 **Reader:** Normal RFID Reader

Now, the thing is, I'm trying to figure out what's up with this tag. I need to convert this code into a hexadecimal for matching purposes. According to an app called NFC Tools, this tag is supposed to be a "MiFare Classic 1k ISO 14443-3A."

I'm scratching my head wondering why the readings don't match up. Possible different ways to read the data?

I already try:

Scan with both readers, check the Reader try to convert to hexadecimal but dont be the correct value

Comment: Converting 3108611405 to HEX results as B949AD4D  so if you try to convert it, it will not provide the correct results as intended.  Some readers and some rfid have different capabilties, and so will "not work as intended" with a reader that does not support them.

Comment: You need a reader that supports Crypto-1 algorithm

Comment: Just my 2 cents - relying any process (e.g. like access control) on the "unique" UID for matching purposes is a realy bad idea - did you ever read about "magic" Mifare Classic tags ? They allow to change the 4 or 7 bytes long UID to any value you like to give - this is the perfect start for a "clone" of the tag. Better rely on data that is "hidden" like an individual key secured block on Mifare Classic or better AES-128 encrypted on Mifare DESFire.

Comment: Hello @MichaelFehr, that is a good idea but for this project is for a second access…. And sadly can’t buy/change any of the current keys. I just maybe go and get a second reader with the same way to read the tags…

Answer (score 0):

Common different ways that the Non Unique ID can be read.

Some readers only read the first 4 bytes of a 7 byte ID.

Some reader read all 7 bytes.

Some readers return the ID in the reverse byte order.

A Mifare Classic EV1 1k can also be configured to return it's ID in 4 different ways, one of which includes a random ID or a calculated 4 byte ID from the 7 byte ID (I don't know how this is calculated).  Normally all genuine Tags from NXP should start with `04h` and a random ID should start with `08h`.

But none of these seem to fit your data.

I would use the NXP Taginfo App on an Android of iPhone to look at the Tag ID's to compare to what your 2 readers are giving and do repeated reads to check that the Tag is not set to Random ID.

I don't think there is a way to check which of the 4 different ID modes a Tag is operating in.

Comment: It's quite strange, I tried to access the memory with NFC Tools of Android, the first Sector is the one that is written and the UID that appears in the Tag I'm trying to read and does not match at all... I don't know if it has some kind of reference... but it doesn't match.

ID - A5:F4:B3:CD

Comment: Without knowing the code that the other reader use, it hard to tell what is done, NFC Tools for Android is good but not as good as the "Tag Info" App for Android from NXP is better as you say it's a MiFare Classic 1k (as this App is from the manufacturer of genuine Mifare Tags) The ISO 14443-3 ID is not a reference to anything and only the first byte A5 should be the manufacturer ID, and from the lists I've seen they don't got that high a Mifare chip should begin with `04`